# Taking the address of a c++ reference for passing to a pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference

I want to pass a c++ reference to a c style API that only allows pointer arguments for passing custom data.

In my example i simply cast the address of the c++ reference into a pointer to void (which happens in a function called "**function**"). This pointer is being passed to a c function (which is called "**execute**") which also takes a callback function as a parameter. Inside the callback functions implementation (named "**callback**") i cast the pointer to void back to a pointer to std::vector.

This compiles without warning(s) and error(s) in MS Visual Studio 2017 and runs as desried (the vector "**v**" contains the numbers from 1 to 5 and they are also printed). However i'm afraid wether this is valid according to the C++ standard.

Of course there is the possiblity of using a global std::vector instance. But under some circumstances, as in my case, this might be a bad solution. Because in my case i need an instance of std::vector per call to "**function**", therefore it's not suitable to have one global instance replacing the parameter. Also global instances might be inappropriate in multithreaded environments, where i want to keep instances of std::vector on the calling stack per thread. Wrapping the std::vector instance by a class and passing a pointer to a std::vector member is also not really what i'm looking for. I'm rather curious about the technical view on the specific implementation i have used.

In a nutshell, would we consider this example a bad practice? Is it valid to take the address of a reference to **Type** into a pointer to void and cast back from a pointer to void into a pointer to **Type** while neglecting that the pointee originally was a reference to **Type**. Are there alternatives instead of the ones i have described above?

Please find the minimal working example below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

//
// The API of a 3rd party library (Typical C-Style Interface)
//

void execute(void (*callback)(void *, int[], int), void * context)
{
    int data [5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    (*callback)(context, data, 5);
}

//
// My callback function fitting the signature for the 3rd party API
//

void callback(void * context, int data [], int size)
{
    std::vector<int> * v = (std::vector<int> *)context;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        v->push_back(data[i]);
    }
}

//
// Pass a reference to an std::vector as void * to the 3rd party API
//

void function(std::vector<int> & v)
{
    execute(callback, (void *)&v);
}

//
// Pass a std::vector as reference to a function
//
// Evaluate the result at the end
//

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    function(v);

    for (auto & e : v) {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are *not* passing a "reference" to the C-style API, you're passing a plain old pointer (to the *original* object, the vector `v` in the `main` function).

Comment: `&v` is of type `std::vector<int>*` - a pointer to vector. You can drop `(void*)` cast, it would work just as well.

Comment: Yes i know that i am not passing a "reference". But i am taking the address of a reference for passing. It is basically the validity of this operation i'm asking about.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I changed the title to better fit the actual question.

Comment: "In my example i simply cast the c++ reference into a pointer to void".  That would be wrong, but that's not what you're doing.  You're casting the *address* of the C++ reference into a pointer to void, which is perfectly fine.  (Yes, it's true, under the hood, the reference really is a pointer, so taking the address of it doesn't really do anything, but again, it's the right way to do it.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. You're right of course. I missed to be precise at that point and corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually do anything with a reference variable except initialize it on definition. Every use of the reference variable after initialization is a direct access to the original variable, what it references.

In your case, when you do `&v` in the function `function`, you don't get the address of the local reference variable `v`, but the address of the variable `v` from the `main` function.

In short, this is fine.